# Why not get total paypal account balance but available balance?

Tags: paypal

```
            GetBalanceReq req = new GetBalanceReq();  
            GetBalanceRequestType reqType = new GetBalanceRequestType();
            /*
             * (Optional) Indicates whether to return all currencies. It is
             * one of the following values: 0 Return only the balance for
             * the primary currency holding. 1 Return the balance for each
             * currency holding.
             */
            // 0Return only the balance for the primary currency holding
            // 1Return the balance for each currency holding 
            // Return the balance is valiable balance not total balance 
            reqType.setReturnAllCurrencies("1");
            req.setGetBalanceRequest(reqType);
            GetBalanceResponseType resp = service.getBalance(req);
```

The getbalance can only get paypal merchant account balances are available, and I want to get to paypal merchant account balance.
What should I do to get the total balance to paypal merchant account?

Comment: Have you try to include the RETURNALLCURRENCIES = 0 in your request?

Comment: Yes, but that is only returns the preferred currency balance?

Comment: The getbalance API only return the balance of the currency that you are holding currently and not total of all balance that you have. To get the total balance you might need to sum up on your end.

Comment: Holding is also available balance, still can not get the total balance, get the available balance of the total balance. But in the paypal account shows that the total balance of businesses including available and unavailable two parts, what I want is added up to the total balance of the two parts! Paypal to provide access to, not with balance this interface?